# Disable submit button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to disable submit button in angularJs to prevent duplicate response from service.

I am new to angularJs and also this should be supported in IE 8.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate response? are you trying to block multiple form submissions?

Comment: duplicate response is if I call a GET service, upon clicking the submit multiple number of times I call GET service multiple number of times and hence I get duplicate results. So, I want to disable the submit button after a single click until it loads the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following approach works for me.

View:

```
<button ng-disabled="isBusy" ng-click="buttonClick()">Load</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    $scope.isBusy = true;
    service.getData()
    .success(function (data) {
        // Use the data
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // Log the error
    })
    .finally(function () {
        $scope.isBusy = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Would this also work without using ng-click directive, but specifying <button type="submit" ng-disabled="..."> ? In this case the button look visually disabled, but triggers "submit" events on my controller.